# How to connect Twillio Voice with Azure Bot Service?

Tags: azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I want to implement a use case where users can call on a number and the whole conversation should be handled by a conversational AI. Is there any way to connect Twilio programable voice with azure bot service (with Directline Speech or any other way). I don't want to use IVR here. I want a connection where the whole media content(user's voice) should be pass to azure bot service/middleware and in response, I should be able to send a text or a .wav file.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but have you considered and/or tried the new Telephony channel for bot framework? It wouldn't use Twilio but it would allow you to create a phone number you can call into and interact with the bot just like other channels. It should work OOTB just by connecting it up, but you'll likely need some modifications to your bot code if you're using things like cards or you want to use upgraded speech capabilities like Neural Voices and SSML.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, connecting directly to a bot via a voice call doesn't appear to be possible, at this time. There isn't an equivalent "call" endpoint for the request URL that matches the `https://sms.botframework.com/api/sms` used for the SMS request URL.

You may be able to design an endpoint of your own that forwards the incoming voice stream. In this case, you would use the [Direct Line Speech](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/direct-line-speech) SDK to, essentially, build your own connector. The processed stream could then be forwarded to your bot for a response. Once a response is returned from the bot, send the response back conforming to Twilio's Programmable Voice [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice).